# Enable CORS origin

Tags: javascript, cors, geoserver

I'm using my localhost geoserver to display the data in webworldwind application (using javascript and html).

I got the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

1. I solved this issue by add an extension **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: ** in the chrome
2. But, I need javascript code for CORS ORIGIN to add in my application instead of the extension i used in browser

I didn't found any solution. I'm drained by searching.

Comment: Wait so you parse the WebWorldWin data on your backend then sending it your your client? Cors-origin is typically server related.

Comment: It depends on whatever is running `http://localhost:8080`, not on your JavaScript/HTML client.

Comment: According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty/212994) you should have some options in `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml`. But you may also need to set some webworldwind specific options that I can't find (NASA guys...) . One solution that would work however would be to setup a simple proxy from `:80` to `:8080`

Comment: @Quentin allow me to disagree with your mjolnir use : The question at hand doesn't ask **why** it doesn't work, but "*how to make it work within the specific setup *webworldwind + geoserver*.* I ever this question is reopened, please add [[tag:geoserver]] to it.

Comment: is there any possibility to write a code in my application to work this @Kaiido

Comment: Certainly yes, but I don't know webworldwind nor GeoServer, and don't have it at hand, nor will I install it only for you (sorry) so I can't tell you exactly what will work and what won't, but did you have a look at [the link I gave to you](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty/212994) ? Is this setting enough ? Otherwise, you might have to look yourself in webworldwind config files anything about `cross-origin`.

Comment: s i have tried but it didn't work ... 
i will look in WWW 
and thq